Why are my SF CLI deployment errors in other language than English?
I'm trying to build an unlocked package and there are some errors received. I'm not concerned about the issues themselves though, the problem is that they are in German:
[...]
ScreenFlowOperatorComponent: EditContactInfoSubflow (Subflow) - Der Flow ScreenFlowEditContactInfo ist nicht vorhanden.
[...]
Account.Flag__c: Feld PersonBirthdate ist nicht vorhanden. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise.
[...]

We indeed have a DevHub instance set for German/Austrian locale, but my own settings are configured to English:


Question: Is there any way to receive deployment/build messages in English without changing Org's default locale?
